# Unable to create the image in MicroStack

Tags: openstack

I installed Ubuntu MicroStack on HP Proliant DL360 Gen9 Server. I followed the MicroStack installation procedure from the MicroStack website.

Everything was OK. However, when I decided to upload an Linux image in the MicroStack. I followed the instructions that I found in the official OpenStack website.  However, the computer screen sent the following message:

Unable to create the image

Nothing more appeared on the computer screen. Any idea how to fix this problem?Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the nginx that is serving horizon has limited the upload size. I'm not a snap expert, so this might not be the "right" way to do it, but it will work around the issue (edit side to your taste):

edit /var/snap/microstack/common/etc/nginx/snap/nginx.conf. In the "http" section, add something like

```
client_max_body_size 4G;
```

Save that, then reload nginx with:

```
/snap/microstack/current/usr/sbin/nginx -s reload -c /var/snap/microstack/common/etc/nginx/snap/nginx.conf
```

You can also add new images with something like (change image and password):

```
microstack.openstack --os-username=admin --os-password=keystone image create --file ./path_to_an_image.img --public --container-format bare --disk-format qcow2 'MyImage'
```