# Image and Instance Issues on MicroStack

Tags: openstack

I have a fresh installation of MicroStack (Ussuri). I have been trying to create an Ubuntu image and instantiate it. Nothing is working from GUI as well as CLI. But, I have been able to create the image using the following command (**Source:** [Unable to create the image in MicroStack](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1223838/unable-to-create-the-image-in-microstack) ):

```
microstack.openstack --os-username=admin --os-password=pass image create --file bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64.img --public --container-format bare --disk-format qcow2 'Ubuntu18'
```

However, It's not possible to create the instance neither from GUI nor from CLI. Any kind of help will be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I can upload the image and create the instance from the CLI but not from the GUI. The instance command is as follows:
microstack.openstack server create --image Ubuntu18(your image name) --flavor m1.medium(your choice) --network test(it is already set in microstack) --key-name  instance_name